# How can I resample an audio file programatically in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioengine, avaudiofile

I would like to know if it's possible to resample an already written `AVAudioFile`.

All the references that I found don't work on this particular problem, since:

- They propose the resampling while the user is recording an `AVAudioFile`, while `installTap` is running. In this approach, the `AVAudioConverter` works in each buffer chunk given by the `inputNode` and appends it in the `AVAudioFile`. [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792936/avaudioconverter-with-avaudioconverterinputblock-stutters-audio-after-processing) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40823574)

The point is that I would like to resample my audio file regardless of the recording process.

The harder approach would be to upsample the signal by a L factor and applying decimation by a factor of M, using [vDSP](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp):

> Audio on Compact Disc has a sampling rate of 44.1 kHz; to transfer it to a digital medium that uses 48 kHz, method 1 above can be used with L = 160, M = 147 (since 48000/44100 = 160/147). For the reverse conversion, the values of L and M are swapped. Per above, in both cases, the low-pass filter should be set to 22.05 kHz. [[3]](http://Audio%20on%20Compact%20Disc%20has%20a%20sampling%20rate%20of%2044.1%20kHz;%20to%20transfer%20it%20to%20a%20digital%20medium%20that%20uses%2048%20kHz,%20method%201%20above%20can%20be%20used%20with%20L%20=%20160,%20M%20=%20147%20(since%2048000/44100%20=%20160/147).%5B5%5D%20For%20the%20reverse%20conversion,%20the%20values%20of%20L%20and%20M%20are%20swapped.%20Per%20above,%20in%20both%20cases,%20the%20low-pass%20filter%20should%20be%20set%20to%2022.05%20kHz.)

The last one obviously seems like a too hard coded way to solve it. I hope there's a way to resample it with [AVAudioConverter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioconverter), but it lacks documentation :(

Comment: This can be done using `AVAudioConverter` by setting a different sample rate for the output format.

Comment: have you successfully resample by AVAudioConverter? I also need this...